# Make error class disappear after few seconds - (foundation-rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, zurb-foundation

Using foundation rails, I have made a form and used `<small class="error">Invalid entry</small>` to display the errors below the fields.

for example, inside a div :

```
<%= text_field_tag "email", "", placeholder: "Email", required: true, type: "email", pattern: "email" %>
<small class="error error-style">Invalid</small>
```

error-style is a class I have used to do the css styling.

If a user starts to fill the form, and fills an invalid email eg. not containing @, the error is displayed. But it remains there. I want it to go into 'hidden' state after about 5 seconds, incase the user decided to not fill the form, but is still browsing the page.

Tried using setTimeout and fadeout().

Any help ?

Comment: what happened when you used the 2 methods you mentioned? please show your code

Comment: I tried something similar to the answer given by Navin below. What happens is explained in the comment. Please have a look.

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
$(function() {
  setTimeout(function(){
    $('.error').slideUp(3000);
  }, 3500);
});
```

Comment: I tried this before, but what happens is - it slides up after the duration 3000. But at load page time, the error is already in hidden state(foundation default). It sliding up has no effect what-so-ever. By default foundation makes the error visible only if the user enters something wrong. I need it to slide up/hide 3-4 seconds after it comes in visible state.

Answer (score 0):

To show and remove an error element during front end validation, you may want to use the 'change' event. Initially, give the error element a class of hide which has display none on it, you can then alter it with the change event. The example below uses addClass and removeClass but you could also use [toggleClass](http://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/).

```
<%= text_field_tag "email", "", placeholder: "Email", required: true, type: "email", pattern: "email", id: "email_input" %>
<small class="error error-style hide">Invalid</small>
```

javascript

```
function email_is_valid(email) {
  var regex = /[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+.[A-Z]{2,4}/;
  return regex.test(email);
}

$('#email-input').on('change', function(event) {
  $(this).find('.error').addClass('hide');
  var email = $(this).val();

  if (email_is_valid(email)){
    $(this).find('.error').removeClass('hide');
  }
});
```

css

```
.hide{
  display: none;
}
```

I've added an id to the input element for easy targeting as I dont know your full markup;  you may want to change how you target that element. Also I've not tested the above regex, there are plenty of resources online where you can find a suitable one.